# Как обработать пустую ячейку при парсинге таблицы html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

При парсинге таблицы встречаются ячейки, где нет данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код в существующем виде просто пропускает это значение, ничего не возвращает. Я потом делаю таблицу при помощи `pandas` и в этом месте значения слетают с правильных ячеек.

```
for cell in row.findAll("td"):
    try:
        d_list.append(cell.string.strip())
    except AttributeError:
        pass
        
    if cell == None:
        print("empty")
        
    print ('\n\t\t\t'.join(d_list))
    
    if len(d_list)== 6:
        print(type(d_list))
        print(d_list)
        mc_list.append(d_list)
        d_list = []
        
    return mc_list
```

Как сделать так, чтобы код возвращал в таких ячейках строку "empty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте проверку. Например `if not cell.string:` сработает и на пустых строках, и на `None`:

```
if not cell.string:
    d_list.append("empty")
else:
    d_list.append(cell.string.strip())
```

Если нужно проверять только на `None`, тогда: `if cell.string is None`

---

Привожу пример таблицы с пустой ячейкой и примером обработки:

```
text = """\
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>cba</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for tr in root.find_all('tr'):
    items = []

    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        if not td.string:
            items.append('<empty>')
        else:
            items.append(td.string.strip())

    # По традиции, в одну строку:
    # items = ['<empty>' if not td.string else td.string.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]

    print(' | '.join(items))
```

Консоль:

```
1 | <empty> | abc | 2
2 | <empty> | cba | 3
```

Comment: find_all() не вернёт None. `mc_list = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td', text=True)`

Comment: @jfs, странно тогда, почему у автора в вопросе была такая проверка... В принципе, если там будет пустая строка `not cell` на нее сработает

Comment: Если бы код в вопросе не был сломан, то и вопроса бы не было.

Comment: @gil9red, по вашему первому совету попробовал. К сожалению не вышло. Опять пропуск в этом месте, то есть никакой строки. '37', 'ОЖЭК 5', '23', '11110.20', '614', 'http://gosjkh.ru/company/info/31023' Может проблема в том, что в html там между тегами td просто ничего нет? <td><td/>?

Comment: @AlexanderBurtsev, сайт был недоступен когда заходил по ссылке, так что накидал свой пример и обновил ответ

Comment: @gil9red, Спасибо большое! Так оно заработало))